# Pandas DataFrame turn a list of jsons column into informative row, per "id"

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
               'json_col': [ [{'aa' : 1, 'ab' : 1}, {'aa' : 3, 'ab' : 2, 'ac': 6}],
                             [{'aa' : 1, 'ab' : 2, 'ac': 1}, {'aa' : 5}],
                             [{'aa': 3, 'ac': 2}] ]})
df
Out[134]: 
   id                                           json_col
0   1  [{'aa': 1, 'ab': 1}, {'aa': 3, 'ab': 2, 'ac': 6}]
1   2           [{'aa': 1, 'ab': 2, 'ac': 1}, {'aa': 5}]
2   3                               [{'aa': 3, 'ac': 2}]
```

We can see that we have a list of jsons for each id.

I'd like, for each `'id'` and for each corresponding json in its list, to have a `'row'` in the `DataFrame`. So the following `DataFrame` will look like this:

```
   id  aa   ab   ac
0   1   1  1.0  NaN
1   1   3  2.0  6.0
2   2   1  2.0  1.0
3   2   5  NaN  NaN
4   3   3  NaN  2.0
```

We can see, `id '1'` had 2 corresponding jsons in it's list and therefor it gets 2 rows in the new `DataFrame`

Is there a pythonic way to do so using *panda, numpy or json* functionality?

---

### Adding the run times of the solutions

```
setup = """
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
               'json_col': [ [{'aa' : 1, 'ab' : 1}, {'aa' : 3, 'ab' : 2, 'ac': 6}],
                             [{'aa' : 1, 'ab' : 2, 'ac': 1}, {'aa' : 5}],
                             [{'aa': 3, 'ac': 2}] ]})
"""

s1 = """
df = pd.concat(
       [pd.DataFrame(j, index=[i]*len(j)) for i, j in enumerate(df['json_col'], 1)],
       sort=False
     )                             
"""

s2 = """
recs = df.apply(lambda x: [{**{'id': x.id}, **d} for d in x.json_col], axis=1).sum()
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(recs)
"""

%timeit(s1, setup)
52.3 ns ± 2.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
%timeit(s2, setup)
50.6 ns ± 3.28 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one quick way by converting all the `json_col`'s lists of dictionaries to `DataFrame` and concatenating them together plus some tweaks to create the `id` column:

```
In [51]: df = pd.concat(
           [pd.DataFrame(j, index=[i]*len(j)) for i, j in enumerate(json_col, 1)],
           sort=False
         )

In [52]: df.index.name = 'id'

In [53]: df.reset_index()
Out[53]: 
   id  aa   ab   ac
0   1   1  1.0  NaN
1   1   3  2.0  6.0
2   2   1  2.0  1.0
3   2   5  NaN  NaN
4   3   3  NaN  2.0
```

Comment: Ali solution work faster, but it's more python and easy to understand, So I'll accept this one

Comment: @EranMoshe It's very likely that the other answer works a little bit slower though.

Comment: I thought so too.. But `timeit` proved me wrong. I might misused it.. You wanna give it a go ?

Comment: @EranMoshe Oh, that's interesting! Can you please update your question with the benchmarks? Thanks.

Comment: After checking it again, they run roughly the same. I'll edit it though.

Answer (score 1):

a short way to accomplish this would be the following, although I don't *personally* consider it very pythonic as the code is a little hard to read, and not terribly performant, but for small data wrangling this should do the trick:

```
recs = df.apply(lambda x: [{**{'id': x.id}, **d} for d in x.json_col], axis=1).sum()
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(recs)
# outputs:
   aa   ab   ac  id
0   1  1.0  NaN   1
1   3  2.0  6.0   1
2   1  2.0  1.0   2
3   5  NaN  NaN   2
4   3  NaN  2.0   3
```

---

#### How it works:

1. The applied lambda creates a new dictionary by merging the contents of `{id: x.id}` to each dictionary in the list of dictionaries in `x.json_col` (where x is a row).
2. This is then summed. Since summing a lists of list of elements unites them into a big list of elements, recs has the following form

   ```
   [{'id': 1, 'aa': 1, 'ab': 1},
    {'id': 1, 'aa': 3, 'ab': 2, 'ac': 6},
    {'id': 2, 'aa': 1, 'ab': 2, 'ac': 1},
    {'id': 2, 'aa': 5},
    {'id': 3, 'aa': 3, 'ac': 2}]
   ```
3. A new data frame is then simply constructed from the records.